# Convert embedded videos in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a few .pptx with Quicktime videos embedded in them.
Powerpoint x64 doesn't support Quicktime (since Microsoft doesn't like Apple) and won't play them.
I know the manual way to extract and convert the videos to another format (and save back). Is there a tool to automate that?

Comment: btw, you should no longer have Quicktime on any Windows machine. Apple deprecated it for Windows & it is no longer considered secure.  Ref: https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA16-105A

Comment: >> Powerpoint x64 doesn't support Quicktime (since Microsoft doesn't like Apple)  ... or because Apple never bothered to release a 64-bit Windows version of Quicktime, probably because they planned to deprecate Quicktime in any form (see Tetsujin's link). It's unlikely that MS would cut off its own customers' noses to spite Apple's face.

Comment: In any case, StackOverflow is for getting help with code that you're developing, not for product recommendations. SuperUser might be a better venue for your question about existing tools to accomplish this.

Comment: 1) On a copy of the file, change the extension of the file to `.ZIP` 2) Unzip the file. 3) Find the Quicktime files in the resulting directories (look for something like `/ppt/media/` or `/ppt/embeddings/`). 4) Use a video conversion utility to resave them in the format you prefer 5) Insert the new files in the PPTX

Comment: Right; do  you have a script that does that for 15 files?